# jQuery best practice for adding URL values with forward/backward button support

Tags: jquery, url, hash, browser-history

I've been digging around the internet and havn't found any recent articles on adding hashes and values to URLs with some mojo baked in.

I'm working on a web app and my ultimate goal is to add a hash to the url for "pages" and add a value after that designating which video on the "page" is in the active state. With it, I'll be enabling bookmarking and direct linking to the videos within the page. I.E.    `localhost#pageTwo?videoTitle`

It seems like Ben Alman's [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) + [Hashchange](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) are the best answers... But they're getting stale and there might be a better answer that I'm not finding.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

The knockout.js tutorial for a [single page app](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail) make use of a plugin called [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/). It has quite a bit of mojo baked in, more than I could wrap my head around. I've only used Sammy for the tutorial there for knockout, but it was very straightforward. Check it out, maybe it will work for you. Though to be fair, I haven't tried either of jQuery BBQ or Hashcage.

Post back, let me know how it pans out.